# How to change IOS badge notification colour from default Red to other colours?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

The default APNS allows a number (badge) to appear in Red background on top of our app icon to state that there is a new notification.

Is there a way to change the Red colour background to any other colours based on the backend server output?

Comment: There is no way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible with public iOS SDK APIs

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html), you cannot change the color or size of the pending notification badge.

> A badge is a small red oval that displays the number of pending notification items (a badge appears over the upper-right corner of an app’s icon). You have no control over the size or color of the badge.

If however you are just curious on how to do it, there is a sample project [here](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge).

Answer (score 0):

Apple not allow to access the UILocalnotification properties so we can not change any thing in uilocal notification , we can only use its default properties