# How can i change badge default color when i used UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change IOS badge notification colour from default Red to other colours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468748/how-to-change-ios-badge-notification-colour-from-default-red-to-other-colours)

I am developing iOS app in which i am using badge for user notification ,but i am unable to change the badge default color please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This component will allow you to put an iOS Badge-like everywhere in your application. So it is now not limited to the UITabBar or to the application icon.

You can change its color, size, set it to have a shadow or not, and to blink, change its font color and size, etc.

Review This link May be helped You....

http://www.binpress.com/app/badges-view-for-ios/338

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the badge with the number in it that goes on your app icon on the home screen, you're out of luck. Red is what you get there. IIRC the same goes for tab bar badges.